# Save data as part of Docker image?

Tags: docker, ghost-blog, ghost

I'm trying to create a custom Docker image for Ghost (https://ghost.org/) with some themes pre-installed. I pulled the official image (https://hub.docker.com/_/ghost/) and installed the Uno Zen (https://github.com/Kikobeats/uno-zen) theme as per the instructions - clone into `content/themes`, run the setup script etc.

I then ran `docker commit` to push these changes as another layer on the existing Docker image. However, the next time I spin up a container using this image, I do not see the theme files where they should be. It's like none of the changes persisted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that /var/lib/ghost/content is declared as a volume:

```
ENV GHOST_CONTENT /var/lib/ghost/content
...
VOLUME $GHOST_CONTENT
```

When a directory is declared as a volume in a Dockerfile, any modifications made on it are not saved afterwards when building or committing a new image.

A possible workaround would be to copy the `/var/lib/ghost/content` to another, say, `/var/lib/ghost/content.real` and reconfigure.  You may add these commands to your Dockerfile (I suggest you make your changes in a Dockerfile instead of run & commit).

```
 ENV GHOST_CONTENT /var/lib/ghost/content.real
 RUN cp -a /var/lib/ghost/content "$GHOST_CONTENT"; \
        gosu node ghost config --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 2368 --no-prompt --db sqlite3 --url http://localhost:2368 --dbpath "$GHOST_CONTENT/data/ghost.db"; \
        gosu node ghost config paths.contentPath "$GHOST_CONTENT"

 VOLUME "$GHOST_CONTENT"
```

Hints taken from the original Dockerfile:

https://github.com/docker-library/ghost/blob/a9b023e922f4f44c4c15f765973c2939f1be9b12/1/debian/Dockerfile

Comment: well TIL. thanks for this. any suggestions as to how i can achieve what i'm looking to do?

Comment: so as per your suggestion of using a Dockerfile instead, should i make the setup procedure for the theme part of my Dockerfile as well?

Comment: Yes. You can achieve that with a combination of the `COPY` and `RUN` directives.